# Specify condition within preset comparison operator?

Tags: google-sheets, named-function

I am experimenting with Named Functions in Google Sheets and trying to make a function to take start and end date arguments to look between within a custom formula. I cannot figure out how to put the dates in a preset comparison and work properly. (i.e. `">=start_date"`) will not accept the `start_date` as an argument of the named function.If the `start_date` variable is outside the parentheses, a formula parse error occurs.

I want to be able to input a date (i.e.`"1/1/1969"`) into my function and have the `">="` to be automatic.

For a simpler experiment I want to have `MYFUNC` perform a `SUMIF` after checking if a given value is `">="`:

Named Function syntax:

```
MYFUNC(sum_range,criteria)
```

Function definition:

```
=SUMIF(sum_range,">=criteria")
```

Example:

```
=MYFUNC(A1:A69,2)
```

My goal is that this example would sum the range A1:A69 if it was greater than or equal to two.

Named function syntax:

```
=MYFUNC(sum_range,date_range,start_date,end_date,criteria_range,criteria,placeholder)
```

Formula definition of my named function:

```
=IF(SUMIFS(sum_range,date_range,">=start_date",date_range,"<=end_date",criteria_range,criteria)=0,placeholder, SUMIFS(sum_range,date_range,">=start_date",date_range,"<=end_date",criteria_range,criteria))
```

I attempted populating the MYFUNC `start_date` and `end_date` as `"1/1/1969"` with and without quotes. This does not populate the function with a date and results in zero value while if I use the formula definition in a cell, it functions and sums the values properly.

[image]

Comment: =IF(SUMIFS(sum_range,date_range,CONCATENATE(">=",start_date),date_range,CONCATENATE("<=",end_date),criteria_range,criteria)=0,placeholder, SUMIFS(sum_range,date_range,CONCATENATE(">=",start_date),
date_range,CONCATENATE("<=",end_date)
,criteria_range,criteria))

I used the CONCATENATE function within my Named Function to achieve my goal. Hope this helps someone else.

Answer (score 0):

To specify a condition within a preset comparison operator in a Google Sheets named function, you can use the IF function in the same way as you would in a regular formula.

As an example you use the following ;

```
function compareValues(val1, val2) {
  return IF(val1>val2, "val1 is greater than val2", "val1 is not greater than val2");
}
```